# How to update @Transient member

Tags: hibernate, jpa

I have a class like this

```
@Entity
public class Order {
  ...
  ...
  @Transient
  private OrderDetail detail;

  private Integer orderDetailId;
}

@Entity
public class OrderDetail {
  ...
  ...
}
```

Note: This is an existing class. I use JPA/Hibernate

I want to update OrderDetail through Order object. How can I achieve it?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

You have marked `detail` as transient. Since it is not persistent you cannot update it.

Isn't there a relation between `Order` and `OrderDetail`?

Comment: Do you think this will work?
    Order order = (Order) session.get(Order.class, 1);
    newOrderDetail.setId(order.getOrderDetailId());
    order.setOrderDetail(newOrderDetail);
    
    session.merge(order); //I was thinking this would do a cascade merge

Comment: Why are you not using a OneToOne relationship?

Comment: I got the solution. I set the existing id in a newly created detail object and will do a session.merge on that one.